# How can I separate the raw_input string without quotations mark? only comma and spaces only

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

My professor gave us this problem and he wants us to do it without using `.join()`.
We input the string or integer that we want then we'll create it as a sets.

For example:

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Fruits = {apple, banana. orange}
```

The output should look like that.

My problem was every time I run the code the result doesn't have comma's.
But if I use the `.join()` I'll get what I needed.

```
#Code for Problem 8
name_of_set = raw_input("")

sets = ""
sets += raw_input("")

setA = ""
setA += "{"
for set in sets:
  sets.split(", ")
setA += sets
setA += "}"

print name_of_set + " = " + setA
```

For example *expected result*:

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4}
Fruits = {apple, banana. orange}
```

Comment: Hint: `("{}"*3).format(1,2,3)`

Comment: @Tiw Why was my edit rejected? Surely minor paragraphing and ticks would be worth an Improve, not a Reject and Edit.

Comment: Another hint: `print(1, 2, 3, sep="")` (but this won't work if you're using python 2- which you shouldn't be learning anyway)

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut  Tag-only edit without fixing other problems.  I showed you the proper way to do it, if I improve edit it you probably won't even check the edit again. If you don't want to spend much effort to really *improve* posts you can leave it to others, or you can earn 2k rep first, by then your edits need not to be reviewed by others. If you have doubt about this you can ask a question on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: That should be a comma after banana and not a period, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand with your input. But this code may helps:

```
name_of_set = input("")
sets = input("")

setA = "{"
elements = sets.split(" ")
x = ""
for element in elements:
    x += element + ","
x = x[:-1]    
setA += x
setA += "}"

print (name_of_set + " = " + setA)
```